# HTML5 Video with Flash fallback not working

Tags: html, flash, video, flv, fallback

I am trying to use a video element for HTML5 video and a nested  element for Flash fallback. I have seen code using flowplayer to fallback to flash - but their documentation only shows a javascript interface. Is there any way to do something like what is below? To test, I remove the two lines with "source src="... "

If I have to use javascript for the flash, how would I code it in line with HTML5?

Thanks!

```
<video id="movie" width="640" height="360" preload controls>
  <source src="./videos/fiddler-tradition.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis" />
  <source src="./videos/fiddler-tradition.mp4" />
  <object id="flowplayer" width="640" height="360" 
        data="./flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

        <param name="movie" value="./flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />

        <param name="flashvars"
            value='config={"clip":"./videos/fiddler-tradition.flv"}' />
   </object>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above non java flowplayer code (the code within the object tag) works fine when outside the video tags. I realize my issue is testing the fallback without html5 on my localhost machine while all I have available is an html5 browser. I will upload to the web and try on another pc with an older browser.

UPDATE: All is working - Testing in IE7, the code falls back to flash player. Yeah!